# Obtaining the position (first and last) of a specific value that is not null in a array

Tags: javascript

I'have the next array:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,2,10,29,43,45,40,54,39,13,1,null,null,null,null,null]
```

I need to know what is the first position in that array that is NOT null and the last that is NOT null too.

In this particular example, first will be 6 (counting 0 as position 1) and 15.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried writing a [simple `for(;;;)` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var firstPos = -1, lastPos = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] !== null) {
        if(firstPos == -1) {
            firstPos = i;
        }
        lastPos = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using non-standard array methods:

```
var arr = [null,null,null,null,null,null,2,10,29,43,45,40,54,39,13,1,null,null,null,null,null];

var mapped = arr.map(function (i) {
    "use strict";    
    return i !== null;
}); 

var first = mapped.indexOf(true);
var second = mapped.lastIndexOf(true);
```

Both [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) require IE9+ browsers or shims. However, they do look really cool.